# Best Java libraries in 2011

Tags: java

What Java libraries would you recommend in the 2011?

I know that there were some question like that, but I'm also interested in new libraries.

Comment: The Java Runtime Library is nice...

Comment: Funny, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries is a real question... mine is not. I really don't know why community is so funny here.

Comment: Since that question was originally asked, the [policies](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) regarding subjective/poll questions have changed. Such questions are more likely to get closed now. Per the FAQ about questions that shouldn't be asked, this falls into the "every answer is equally valid" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little vague as Java is such a huge field today.

Are you talking about desktop development? Mobile (Android) development? Server-side?

At least for the server-side, which is represented by Java EE the trend is to use *less* libraries. A lot of the functionality that is required by most applications is already part of the Java EE 6 platform. Additional libraries are still useful for e.g. extra UI components (PrimeFaces, RichFaces, etc).

Seam 3 though does seem to provide some interesting technology and might be a useful extra library when you use Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries for *what*? General purpose? Bayesian analysis? Image manipulation?

Other than the JDK itself, there's quite a good collection over at [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/), but the question is so vague I have no idea if that's what you're looking for...